# One Specific C++ class doesn't build during Visual Studio build process

Tags: c++, linker-errors, visual-studio-2019

**The Lowdown**

I'm building my own C++ class library to work with some SDK code I downloaded from a [github repository](https://github.com/Slamtec/rplidar_sdk).  This extra class library, which I've dubbed "Hogwash" (it's a long story), is working just fine except for one problem:  my "Average" class, which provides a simple object for adding numbers to a cumulative average before "Get()"-ing the average and clearing the object, simply refuses the compile.  I receiver Linker errors for every function call I make to it.

I found a [nicely descriptive error page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2019?view=vs-2019) for LNK2019, one of the errors I'm getting (is it just me, or is this year haunting me?), which mentions that a potential cause of my errors could be as follows:  The initial pass of the compiler (which transforms preprocessed code into `.obj` code) wasn't compiling the file, so when it came time for the linker to link, that file didn't exist.  Going through the build output, I discovered this to be the case.  The entire build process happened, and all the `.cpp` files were named one by one, except... no `Average.cpp`

The only info the internet had for me was [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36406699/visual-studio-not-compiling-specific-file), which mentions splitting the `.h` and `.cpp` files in two, which of course I've already done by convention.  I've tried removing and re-adding the problem file, in case the problem is some Visual Studio file metadata thing, and that had literally no effect.  I tried completely removing the project, creating a new C++ project, and re-adding all of my project files in, and nothing changed.

So I'm stuck.  Do any wiser than I have ideas?

---

**Helpful stuff**

The compiler output:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Hogwash, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Stdafx.cpp
1>  AssemblyInfo.cpp
1>  HogwashAlgorithm.cpp
1>HogwashAlgorithm.cpp(76): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data
1>  ProcessScanResult.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>  .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.AssemblyAttributes.cpp
1>  AssemblyInfo.obj : /DEBUG:FASTLINK is not supported when managed code is present; restarting link with /DEBUG:FULL
1>HogwashAlgorithm.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000165) "public: void __thiscall Average::Add(float)" (?Add@Average@@$$FQAEXM@Z) referenced in function "public: static class ProcessScanResult __cdecl Hogwash::HogwashAlgorithm::ProcessScan(class std::vector<struct scanDot,class std::allocator<struct scanDot> >)" (?ProcessScan@HogwashAlgorithm@Hogwash@@$$FSA?AVProcessScanResult@@V?$vector@UscanDot@@V?$allocator@UscanDot@@@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>HogwashAlgorithm.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000166) "public: __thiscall Average::Average(void)" (??0Average@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: static class ProcessScanResult __cdecl Hogwash::HogwashAlgorithm::ProcessScan(class std::vector<struct scanDot,class std::allocator<struct scanDot> >)" (?ProcessScan@HogwashAlgorithm@Hogwash@@$$FSA?AVProcessScanResult@@V?$vector@UscanDot@@V?$allocator@UscanDot@@@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>HogwashAlgorithm.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Average::Average(void)" (??0Average@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: static class ProcessScanResult __cdecl Hogwash::HogwashAlgorithm::ProcessScan(class std::vector<struct scanDot,class std::allocator<struct scanDot> >)" (?ProcessScan@HogwashAlgorithm@Hogwash@@$$FSA?AVProcessScanResult@@V?$vector@UscanDot@@V?$allocator@UscanDot@@@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>HogwashAlgorithm.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Average::Add(float)" (?Add@Average@@$$FQAEXM@Z) referenced in function "public: static class ProcessScanResult __cdecl Hogwash::HogwashAlgorithm::ProcessScan(class std::vector<struct scanDot,class std::allocator<struct scanDot> >)" (?ProcessScan@HogwashAlgorithm@Hogwash@@$$FSA?AVProcessScanResult@@V?$vector@UscanDot@@V?$allocator@UscanDot@@@std@@@std@@@Z)
1>C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\HogWash\rplidar_sdk-master\rplidar_sdk-master\sdk\workspaces\vc10\Debug\Hogwash.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

The (entire) Hogwash.vcxproj Project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{69E4290E-77ED-443A-A2D7-ECD4B223E5C6}</ProjectGuid>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <Keyword>ManagedCProj</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>Hogwash</RootNamespace>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>8.1</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v140</PlatformToolset>
    <CLRSupport>true</CLRSupport>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v140</PlatformToolset>
    <CLRSupport>true</CLRSupport>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v140</PlatformToolset>
    <CLRSupport>true</CLRSupport>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v140</PlatformToolset>
    <CLRSupport>true</CLRSupport>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="Shared">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>false</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <LinkIncremental>false</LinkIncremental>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies />
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies />
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;NDEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies />
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>NDEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies />
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="HogwashAlgorithm.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="ProcessScanResult.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="resource.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="scanDot.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="Stdafx.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="AssemblyInfo.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="HogwashAlgorithm.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="ProcessScanResult.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="Stdafx.cpp">
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Text Include="ReadMe.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ResourceCompile Include="app.rc" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Image Include="app.ico" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

The only reference I currently make to Average.h (and its surroundings):

```
// This is the main DLL file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include <math.h>
#include "HogwashAlgorithm.h"
#include "ProcessScanResult.h"
#include "Average.h"


using namespace std;
using namespace Hogwash;

#ifndef HOGWASH_ALGORITHM_H
#define HOGWASH_ALGORITHM_H

...
```

`Average.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

class Average
{
public:
    Average();
    std::vector<float> * numList;
    int count;
    // Add to the current Average
    void Add(float Number);
    // Finish the Average Operation, return the average, and clear the object for a new averaging operation
    float Get();
};
```

`Average.cpp`:

```
#include "Average.h"
#include "Stdafx.h"
#include <numeric>

Average::Average()
{
    this->numList = new std::vector<float>(0);
    this->count = 0;
}

// Add to the current Average
void Average::Add(float Number)
{
    this->numList->push_back(Number);
    this->count++;
}

// Finish the Average Operation, return the average, and clear the object for a new averaging operation
float Average::Get()
{
    float average;
    if (count == 0) {
        average = 0;
    }
    else {
        float average = std::accumulate(this->numList->begin(), this->numList->end(), 0) / this->count;
    }
    this->numList = new std::vector<float>(0);
    this->count = 0;
    return average;
}
```

Comment: Where are the definitions for the `Average` class?

Comment: I see neither `Average.cpp` nor `Average.h` added to your project.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your problem is that you try to add `Average.cpp` to your MSVC project, but the change doesn't reflect itself in the actual vcxproj file, correct?

Comment: @Frank, The change didn't reflect itself at first. When I originally put the project together, I added the Average.cpp/.h files to the project directory and then put "Include In Project". After some tinkering, I went through the project file myself and added my files to the CLInclude's. but nothing changed. So my problem is that the file is just being skipped